# What is the best tools to crawl and index large Filesystem in a database?

Tags: elasticsearch, filesystems, filesystemwatcher

Is there any customizable CLI tools that can watch file system changes, crawl and index file system with contents in a database?

I tried `csearch`, `grep`, `ack`. But it helped me to search from the file system but can't build a complete solutions. I need few features

- Watch file system change
- Exclude/include path with pattern
- Indexing in a database so I can search contents, run aggregated queries

Answer (score 1):

Last month I had to solve a very critical problem that involves crawling, indexing and searching source codes from 29 million files. I tried `grep`, `ack`, `csearch`. However, `csearch` seems faster than others.

But it was very difficult to manage the system and performance was not ready to publish the system public. But then I found `fscrawler`. A Java CLI tools that helped me to crawl the entire Filesystem (29 million of files) and index **file meta-data** + **contents** into *Elasticsearch*. And to discover the best solution, it took me 2 weeks to figure it out. So it's worth sharing with others.

`fscrawler` index data, parse data, generate file meta-data and index in `Elasticsearch`. To get a clear picture, here is the configuration options that you can adjust before crawling and indexing your Filesystem.

```
name: "job_name"
fs:
  url: "/path/to/docs"
  update_rate: "5m"
  includes:
  - "*.doc"
  - "*.xls"
  excludes:
  - "resume.doc"
  json_support: false
  filename_as_id: true
  add_filesize: true
  remove_deleted: true
  add_as_inner_object: false
  store_source: true
  index_content: true
  indexed_chars: "10000.0"
  attributes_support: false
  raw_metadata: true
  xml_support: false
  index_folders: true
  lang_detect: false
  continue_on_error: false
  pdf_ocr: true
  ocr:
    language: "eng"
    path: "/path/to/tesseract/if/not/available/in/PATH"
    data_path: "/path/to/tesseract/tessdata/if/needed"
server:
  hostname: "localhost"
  port: 22
  username: "dadoonet"
  password: "password"
  protocol: "SSH"
  pem_path: "/path/to/pemfile"
elasticsearch:
  nodes:
  # With Cloud ID
  - cloud_id: "CLOUD_ID"
  # With URL
  - url: "http://127.0.0.1:9200"
  index: "docs"
  bulk_size: 1000
  flush_interval: "5s"
  byte_size: "10mb"
  username: "elastic"
  password: "password"
rest:
  url: "https://127.0.0.1:8080/fscrawler"
```

Now I guess you got an idea about how much customization you can do to run the entire operation. 
You can read the documentation from https://fscrawler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html and source codes are hosted on GitHub https://github.com/dadoonet/fscrawler